# C# winforms progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want a progress bar to show the percent of the method left to be executed. The method that is being executed is an ms test. When the user clicks on the button the ms test 
executes and I want a progress bar to show. The ms test is a list of selected workflows. I have a method that gets a list of the  selected workflows - should the 
progress bar be showing a percent of the list of selecte workflows .

At the moment I have a progress bar that shows 05 just for one second and then shows a flowing green bar . This is the code I have behind the Run ms test button

```
RunTestsProgressBar.Refresh();
        int percent = (int)(((double)RunTestsProgressBar.Value / (double)RunTestsProgressBar.Maximum) * 100);
        RunTestsProgressBar.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(RunTestsProgressBar.Width / 2 - 10, RunTestsProgressBar.Height / 2 - 7));
```

Comment: Are you going to do the work on another thread?  Otherwise, your progress bar won't be updated in the UI as your method is being stepped through.

Comment: the method is already working on a background thread .do I use another thread for the progress bar?

Comment: You can only modify the UI on the main (UI) thread.  You'll have to invoke the methods on the main thread from your background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have had to do such things in the past I usually use a **BackgroundWorker** and use its ***ReportProgress()*** method which fires the ***ProgressChanged*** event on the UI thread.

I think this is a good way to go about doing things if you know how many tests you are going to preform and can call ***UpdateProgress*** after each test is complete.

Here is a link to a nice easy to follow example.

[Dot NET Perls - ProgressBar w/ BackgroundWorker](https://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

Comment: It sounds like you are setting the _**Style**_ property of the **ProgressBar** to _Marquee_.  Try setting it to _Block_ or _Continuous_.